# communication protocol of camera in smartphone

Tags: camera, protocols, smartphone

I opened a  smartphone(moto g2) now i need to remove the camera and use it with some other controller/dev boards. do they use standard protocols like i2c /spi for interfacing the camera to motherboard or is there any specific protocol to communicate these pheriperals with the motherboard processor .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to know that generic smartphone camera  use CSI(Camera Serial Interface ) protocol to communicate with the processors.This question is now answered.